# Problems with do while loops, Java

Tags: java, do-while

I'm prompting the user to input an integer and if they don't enter a proper integer (as a reference to an option) then I would like the prompt to show up again until they do.

So far this is the code I have:

```
           int logIn = 0;
    do {
        logIn = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Please:"
                + "\n(Enter number value of option you would like to choose.)\n"
                + "\n1. Log In \n2. Register"));
    } while (1 > logIn || logIn < 2);

    int custIndex;

    if (logIn == 1) {
        custIndex = recommend.getCustomerIndex();
    } else {
        customers.printCustomers();
        custIndex = customers.readCustomers().size();
    }

    int options = 0;
    do {
        options = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Would you like to:"
                + "\n(Enter number value of option you would like to choose.)\n"
                + "\n1. See your recommendations. \n2. See top rated books."
                + "\n3. See random books of the day. \n4. Exit."));
    } while (1 > options || options < 4);
```

The only problem is that my application won't get past the log in correctly. If the user enters 1, it shows them the prompt again; and if the user enters any number higher than 2, it takes them to the second option no matter what.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try some 

    while ((logIn < 1) || (logIn > 2))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `while` condition reads

```
while (1 > logIn || logIn < 2)
```

which means the input must be less than 1 or less than 2 for the loop to continue. What you want is

```
while (logIn < 1 || logIn > 2)
```

or perhaps more legibly

```
while (logIn != 1 && logIn != 2)
```

Comment: Thank you, I had 'while (logIn != 1 && logIn != 2)' earlier, though I just wanted to understand how to do it with '<' and '>' if there were more than 2 options (like in the second part of my code).

Answer (score 3):

looks like your while loop logic is off.
The while loop will go on while logIn is less than 1 OR logIN is LESS THAN 2 (should be greater than).

You probably meant:

do ... while (logIn < 1 || logIn > 2);

Answer (score 1):

Replace with

```
 while (1 != logIn && logIn != 2);
```

Thus, loop will continue if logIn has different value from 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
    logIn = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Please:"
            + "\n(Enter number value of option you would like to choose.)\n"
            + "\n1. Log In \n2. Register"));
} while (logIn != 1 && logIn != 2)
```

Update the login in your code as above :)